# Поле выборка файла на форме

Tags: delphi

Всем привет.
Требуется читать файл Excel который выберет пользователь.
Добавляю на форму TOpenDialog или TOpenDialogFile. Запускаю в открываю форму, на форме пусто, хотя в конфигураторе Я вижу что на форме элемент есть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код открытия дочерней формы

```
procedure TfmTransDocMain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
res:word;

begin
  res :=Form1.ShowModal;
end;
```

Comment: Правильно, это невизуальные компоненты, их надо вызывать из кода.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь понятно почему не вызывались

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/UsingDialogs_(Delphi) вот пример использования